OOTB windows custom ISO
I've been trying to create a custom Windows ISO that includes preinstalled apps, such as 7-Zip and Google Chrome, without having to use a virtual machine to install the apps and then export the ISO. I want a method where I can directly customize the ISO by adding and removing applications, so that the final image is tailored to my needs. I’ve heard of NTLite, but it’s a paid tool, and I'm looking for a free alternative that allows me to modify the ISO itself easily. Are there any free tools or methods available that allow me to customize a Windows ISO with preinstalled apps in a straightforward and effective way?

Try asking on Software Recommendations site
